# Write a for-loop in google earth engine

Tags: r, google-earth-engine

I have a grid shapefileof equal size polygons as shown below

```
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)

dat <- structure(list(ID = 758432:758443, 
                        lat = c(24.875, 24.875, 24.625, 24.625, 24.875, 24.875, 24.625, 24.625, 24.375, 24.375, 24.125, 24.125), 
                        lon = c(72.875, 72.625, 72.625, 72.875, 72.375, 72.125, 72.125, 72.375, 72.375, 72.125, 72.125, 72.375)), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))


dat_rast <- rasterFromXYZ(dat[, c('lon', 'lat', 'ID')], crs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')
dat_poly <- rasterToPolygons(dat_rast, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE, dissolve=FALSE)
```

I want to process the NASA_NEX-GDDP data in the google earth engine

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_NEX-GDDP

This data has 3 variables: pr, tasmin and tasmax and has a resolution of 0.25 arc degrees
and covers the period 1950-01-01 to 2099-12-31

For each polygon in `dat_poly`, I want to calculate mean daily pr, tasmin and tasmax

So far I can do this for a single lat long and a single variable using the following approach in the
code editor

```
 var startDate = ee.Date('1950-01-01');
 var endDate = ee.Date('2099-12-31');
 
 // select the variable to be processed: pr, tasmin, tasmax
 var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP')
 .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate));
 var maximumAirTemperature = dataset.select('tasmax'); 
 
 // get projection information
 var proj = maximumAirTemperature.first().projection(); 
 
 // the lat lon for which I want to extract the data 
 var point = ee.Geometry.Point([72.875, 24.875]); 
 
 // calculate number of days to map and extract data for
 var n = endDate.difference(startDate,'day').subtract(1);
 
 var timeseries = ee.FeatureCollection(
   ee.List.sequence(0,n).map(function(i){
     var t1 = startDate.advance(i,'day');
     var t2 = t1.advance(1,'day');
     var feature = ee.Feature(point);
     var dailyColl = maximumAirTemperature.filterDate(t1, t2);
     var dailyImg = dailyColl.toBands();
     
    // rename bands to handle different names by date
     var bands = dailyImg.bandNames();
     var renamed = bands.map(function(b){
       var split = ee.String(b).split('_');
       return ee.String(split.get(0)).cat('_').cat(ee.String(split.get(1)));
     });
     
     // extract the data for the day and add time information
     var dict = dailyImg.rename(renamed).reduceRegion({
       reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
       geometry: point,
       scale: proj.nominalScale()
     }).combine(
       ee.Dictionary({'system:time_start':t1.millis(),'isodate':t1.format('YYYY-MM-dd')})
     );
     return ee.Feature(point,dict);
   })
 );
 
 Map.addLayer(point);
 Map.centerObject(point,6);
 
 // export feature collection to CSV
 Export.table.toDrive({
   collection: timeseries,
   description: 'my_file',
   fileFormat: 'CSV',
 });
```

Instead of extracting for a given lat lon, how can I calculate the mean daily pr, tasmin and tasmax of each polygon in `my_poly` for the given time period?

Answer (score 3):

The `rgee` package, see [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/rgee) and [here](https://csaybar.github.io/rgee-examples/), allows to stay in R to query Google Earth Engine:

```
#Setup rgee
remotes::install_github("r-spatial/rgee")

library(rgee)

## necessary only once
ee_install()

library(raster)

dat <- structure(list(ID = 758432:758443, 
                      lat = c(24.875, 24.875, 24.625, 24.625, 24.875, 24.875, 24.625, 24.625, 24.375, 24.375, 24.125, 24.125), 
                      lon = c(72.875, 72.625, 72.625, 72.875, 72.375, 72.125, 72.125, 72.375, 72.375, 72.125, 72.125, 72.375)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))


dat_rast <- rasterFromXYZ(dat[, c('lon', 'lat', 'ID')], crs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')
dat_poly <- rasterToPolygons(dat_rast, fun=NULL, na.rm=TRUE, dissolve=FALSE)

# Initialize Earth Engine
ee_Initialize()
#-- rgee 1.0.1 --------------------------------------- earthengine-api 0.1.229 -- 
# √ email: ******@gmail.com 
# √ Initializing Google Earth Engine:  DONE!
# √ Earth Engine user: users/****** 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

# A few days for test
startDate = ee$Date('2020-01-01');
endDate = ee$Date('2020-01-10');


# Open dataset
ImageCollection = ee$ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP')$filter(ee$Filter$date(startDate, endDate))#$filterBounds(polygonsCollection)

# Polygons collection
coords <- as.data.frame(raster::geom(dat_poly))
polygonsFeatures <- coords %>% split(.$object) %>% purrr::map(~{  
  ee$Feature(ee$Geometry$Polygon(mapply( function(x,y){list(x,y)} ,.x$x,.x$y,SIMPLIFY=F)))
})

polygonsCollection = ee$FeatureCollection(unname(polygonsFeatures))
Map$addLayer(polygonsCollection)
```

[image]

```
# Get list of images (1 per day)
ListOfImages = ImageCollection$toList(ImageCollection$size());

# first image
image <- ee$Image(ListOfImages$get(0))

# Add the mean of each band as new properties of each polygon
Means = image$reduceRegions(collection = polygonsCollection,reducer= ee$Reducer$mean())
Means$getInfo()

$type
[1] "FeatureCollection"

$columns
$columns$pr
[1] "Float"

$columns$`system:index`
[1] "String"

$columns$tasmax
[1] "Float"

$columns$tasmin
[1] "Float"


$features
$features[[1]]
$features[[1]]$type
[1] "Feature"

$features[[1]]$geometry
$features[[1]]$geometry$type
[1] "Polygon"

$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates
$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]]
$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[1]]
$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 72

$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] 24.75


$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[2]]
[1] 72.25 24.75

$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[3]]
$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 72.25

$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[3]][[2]]
[1] 25


$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[4]]
[1] 72 25

$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[5]]
$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[5]][[1]]
[1] 72

$features[[1]]$geometry$coordinates[[1]][[5]][[2]]
[1] 24.75





$features[[1]]$id
[1] "0"

$features[[1]]$properties
$features[[1]]$properties$pr
[1] 0

$features[[1]]$properties$tasmax
[1] 298.4862

$features[[1]]$properties$tasmin
[1] 278.2297
...
```

The polygons data can be downloaded on Google Drive:

```
task_vector <- ee_table_to_drive(
  collection = Means,
  fileFormat = "CSV",
  fileNamePrefix = "test"
)
task_vector$start()
ee_monitoring(task_vector)
```

[image]
This gives you access to the average values of each polygon for one day.
You can change the index value to query other days.

To get the complete statistic over all days, you just need to map over the days :

```
# Calculate means for all dates
calcMean <- function(image) {
  image$reduceRegions(collection = polygonsCollection,reducer= ee$Reducer$mean())
}

DayMeans <- ImageCollection$map(calcMean)$flatten()

task_vector <- ee_table_to_drive(
  collection = DayMeans,
  fileFormat = "CSV",
  fileNamePrefix = "DayMeans"
)
task_vector$start()
```

[image]

Comment: @89_Simple, happy that my answer seems to fullfill your needs! Would you mind also accepting it, so that others know it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this doesn't answer your questionm but:

You can use a `for` loop or use `map`. Here what I know:

[image]

[image]

So, maybe you can use `map` in your feature collection and for each of your elements in `dat_poly` you can run the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do all the mapping. I think you can just use `reduceRegions`.

Basically follow these steps:

1. Do the rollup from imageCollection to image by filtering and averaging the values for the bands you want.
2. Load the polygons as a feature collection.
3. Run `reduceRegions` using the image and polygon fc and export.

This will likely take a while, you might need to adjust the scale. It's also possible you'll have to iterate through the polygons if things timeout, but I would first try exporting the `all_data` image as an asset and running the reduction on that.

```
var startDate = ee.Date('1950-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-12-31');
 
 // select the variable to be processed: pr, tasmin, tasmax
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP')
                .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate));
var all_data = dataset.select(['pr', 'tasmin','tasmax']).mean();

var point = ee.Geometry.Point([72.875, 24.875]); 

var scale = 1000; // or whatever

// use the fc with polygons instead of "point"
var answer = all_data.reduceRegions(point, ee.Reducer.first(), scale);
 
Export.table.toDrive(answer);
```